# Alternatives to long if statement

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement, conditional-statements

I currently have a long if statement, which looks ugly, and I'm fairly certain isn't proper. It looks something like this.

```
if self.folderactive.isChecked:
    folders.createDir('Desktop')
elif not self.folderactive.isChecked:
    folders.deleteDir('Desktop')

if self.folderactive_2.isChecked:
    folders.createDir('Documents')
elif not self.folderactive_2.isChecked:
    folders.deleteDir('Documents')

if self.folderactive_3.isChecked:
    folders.createDir('Downloads')
elif not self.folderactive_3.isChecked:
    folders.deleteDir('Downloads')

if self.folderactive_4.isChecked:
    folders.createDir('Music')
elif not self.folderactive_4.isChecked:
    folders.deleteDir('Music')

if self.folderactive_5.isChecked:
    folders.createDir('Pictures')
elif not self.folderactive_5.isChecked:
    folders.deleteDir('Pictures')

if self.folderactive_6.isChecked:
    folders.createDir('Public')
elif not self.folderactive_6.isChecked:
    folders.deleteDir('Public')

if self.folderactive_7.isChecked:
    folders.createDir('Templates')
elif not self.folderactive_7.isChecked:
    folders.deleteDir('Templates')

if self.folderactive_8.isChecked:
    folders.createDir('Videos')
elif not self.folderactive_8.isChecked:
    folders.deleteDir('Videos')
```

How would I go about simplifying this long list of conditionals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, all `elif ...` clause can be written as `else:`.

Multiple `if .. else ..` can be expressed as for loop:

```
checkbox_directory_pairs = [
    (self.folderactive, 'Desktop'),
    (self.folderactive_2, 'Documents'),
    (self.folderactive_3, 'Downloads'),
    ...
]

for checkbox, directory in checkbox_directory_pairs:
    if checkbox.isChecked:
        folders.createDir(directory)
    else:
        folders.deleteDir(directory)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked very well with some minor tweaking. I had to change `if self.folderactive.isChecked:` to `if checkbox.isChecked:`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can simplify a statement like this:

```
if self.folderactive.isChecked:
    folders.createDir('Desktop')
elif not self.folderactive.isChecked:
    folders.deleteDir('Desktop')
```

to

```
if self.folderactive.isChecked:
    folders.createDir('Desktop')
else:
    folders.deleteDir('Desktop')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use associative arrays: checkbox number as index, folder name as value.