# accessing values from a list in python

Tags: python, data-structures

If I had the following code

```
buttonParameters = [
    ("button1", "button1.png"),
    ("button2", "button2.png"),
    ("button3", "button3.png"),
    ("button4", "button4.png"),
    ("button5", "button5.png"),
]
```

how would I go about accessing "button1" from buttonParameters.

Also, what type of list structure is this? I was reccomended using it, but I'm not sure I know what it's name is, and would like to search some to understand it more.

Comment: It is a list of `tuples`. You can read more about tuples [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)

Comment: What you have there is a simple list, but the members of the list are tuples. Why did someone recommend you use this structure? It makes sense for some uses and not others.

Comment: @AndrewGorcester It was reccomended to me at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20455147/alternatives-to-long-if-statement/20455180?noredirect=1#comment30574801_20455180

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to retrieve a *Value* from a mapping, given a *Key*.

For this you are using a List when you should be using a [Dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
buttonParameters = {
    "button1": "button1.png",
    "button2": "button2.png",
    "button3": "button3.png",
    "button4": "button4.png",
    "button5": "button5.png",
}

buttonParameters['button1'] #=> "button1.png"
```

A solution involving a List traversal to extract a value has linear worst-case performance whilst dictionary retrieval is amortised constant time.

You can convert your list of tuples into the above dictionary with:

```
buttonParameters = dict(buttonParameters)
```

Comment: Could I access that using a integer variable? For instance recursively access the first value of each entry?